# Custom `returnFormat` in ColdFusion 10 or 11?

Tags: function, coldfusion, return-type

I've a function which is called from different components, .cfms or remotely. It returns the results of a query.

Sometimes the response from this function is manually inspected - a person may want to see the ID of a specific record so they can use it elsewhere.

The provided return formats, being `wddx, json, plain` all aren't very easily readable for a layman.

I'd love to be able to create a new return format: `dump`, where the result first `writeDump`ed and then returned to the caller.

I know there'd be more complicated ways of solving this, like writing a function `dump`, and calling that like a proxy by providing the component, function and parameters so it can call that function and return the results.

However I don't think it's worth going that far. I figured it'd be great if I could just write a new return format, because that's just... intuitive and nice, and I may also be able to use that technique to solve different problems or improve various workflows.

**Is there a way to create custom function `returnFormat`s in ColdFusion 10 or 11?**

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking but the returnformat is optional.

Comment: A return format basically takes the return value, applies some kind of transformation (i.e. a conversion to "json" or "wddx") and returns that instead. I'm asking if it's possible to create custom return types and transformation functions, so instead of "json" or "wddx" I can use "foo" or "bar", which do what I want them to.

Comment: @BilalAkil You can add a custom attribute to your function and can return output based on that by using function's metadata.

Comment: @Beginner That's fair enough, I was just wondering if there'd be any less.. manual way. I call that manual because I'd need to have the logic that looks at that attribute and transforms the return value repeated (or have that function "manually" called) in every place I use it. If there's no way to specify custom `returnFormat`s then "No." would be a perfectly valid answer to this question.

Comment: What is the return type of the function?

Comment: A query or generally anything you can `writeDump`.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot add a custom returntype to a function, but take a look at [OnCFCRequest](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/application-cfc-reference/oncfcrequest.html). Might be able to use it to build something more generic when a custom URL parameter is passed, ie `url.returnformat=yourType`. Same net effect as dumping and/or manipulating the result manually, just a little more automated.

Comment: Thanks @Leigh. That link looks like it's the next best thing. If you want to write that comment up as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From comments)

AFAIK, you cannot add a custom `returntype` to a cffunction, but take a look at [OnCFCRequest](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/application-cfc-reference/oncfcrequest.html). Might be able to use it to build something more generic that responds differently whenever a custom URL parameter is passed, ie `url.returnformat=yourType`. Same net effect as dumping and/or manipulating the result manually, just a little more automated.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, the return type of the function is query.  That being the case, there is simply no need for a custom return format.  If you want to dump the query results, do so.

```
queryVar = objectName.nameOfFunction(arguments);
writeDump (queryVar);
```